# Power Pivot with combined measures from mutliple table

Tags: powerpivot

I have sums of table columns as measures but for multiple tables. I combined them as sums of measures. On the pivot sheet i want to drill trough but i can't because it belongs to only one table. Are there any better solution for measure combinations? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I assume by the "drill through" you mean what happens when you double click a cell in the pivot. Also, I assume that you've built a [star schema](https://radacad.com/power-bi-basics-of-modeling-star-schema-and-how-to-build-it) with most of the measures in the centre table, and all the tables are keyed together.

You're not going to like this one, but the drill through is determined by the table you associate the measure with, and the records of just that table are returned; so the drill through is actually fairly limited.  Each measure can be associated with any table, not just the one it uses, so if there is one table you want to drill into, you could associate all the measures with that.

But that's probably not really what you want.  The only solution I've found is to create a pivot with the same slicer dependencies that contains all the fields you want on the drill down, and only those ones - so you've got a detail version of the main table on a different sheet. The other thing you might consider is shutting down the drill down functionality by creating an empty table, and associating all the measures with that.